Unknown word (CssSyntaxError) error in Every jsx file
In my react project i use tailwind css. i have installed every package I need. When I run the project, it runs without errors. But, in every jsx file, the first line has an error. it says Unknown word (CssSyntaxError)
Here is my App.jsx file
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import Test from "./pages/Test";
import "./App.css";
import Signup from "./pages/Signup";

const router = createBrowserRouter([

  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Test />,
  },
  {
    path: "/signup",
    element: <Signup />,
  },
]);

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


the line import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom"; has a red underline under createBrowserRouter, the error is Unknown word (CssSyntaxError)
Here is my Signup.jsx file
import React from "react";

const Signup = () => (
  <section className="flex">
    <div className="w-1/2">
      <div className="container mx-auto max-w-2xl p-8 bg-white rounded-lg shadow-md">
        <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold mb-4">Create an account</h1>
        <p className="mb-6 text-gray-500">
          Already have an account?{" "}
          <a href="/login" className="text-primary-shade-1 hover:underline">
            Log in
          </a>
        </p>

        <form>
          {/* First and Last Name */}
          <div className="flex gap-4 mb-4">
            <input
              type="text"
              name="firstName"
              placeholder="First name"
              className="w-full p-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md"
              required
            />
            <input
              type="text"
              name="lastName"
              placeholder="Last name"
              className="w-full p-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md"
              required
            />
          </div>

          {/* Email */}
          <input
            type="email"
            name="email"
            placeholder="Email address"
            className="w-full p-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md mb-4"
            required
          />

          {/* Contact Number */}
          <input
            type="tel"
            name="contactNumber"
            placeholder="Contact Number"
            className="w-full p-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md mb-4"
            required
          />

          {/* Password */}
          <div className="flex gap-4 mb-4">
            <input
              name="password"
              placeholder="Password"
              className="w-full p-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md"
              required
            />
            <input
              name="confirmPassword"
              placeholder="Confirm your password"
              className="w-full p-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md"
              required
            />
          </div>

          <p className="text-gray-500 text-sm mb-4">
            Use 8 or more characters with a mix of letters, numbers & symbols
          </p>

          {/* Checkbox */}
          <div className="flex items-center mb-6">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              name="showPassword"
              className="mr-2 rounded"
            />
            <label htmlFor="showPassword">Show password</label>
          </div>

          {/* Buttons */}
          <div className="flex gap-4">
            <button type="button" className="text-pink-500 hover:underline">
              Log in instead
            </button>
            <button
              type="submit"
              className="bg-pink-500 text-white py-2 px-4 rounded-md hover:bg-pink-600 w-full"
            >
              Create an account
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className="bg-blue-300 w-1/2">Right Side</div>
  </section>
);

export default Signup;

the line import React from "react"; has red underlines under import React. the error is the same. Why is this. How can I fix this?
I tried every suggestion from github copilot. nothing works. all the dependencies are installed

Possibly related

Please provide more information, how does your configuration file look like. What is the encoding of the file. Are you using any formatter, what could be modifying the source code? What build process are you using or framework?
